# How to remove maxDate in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below working fine. But How to remove a maxDate in `StartDate` if I change the `DateEnd`?.

For example my `DateStarted` is `09/26/2016` and the `End` is `09/30/2016` it has a `maxDate and minDate` as you can see each of the code. What I want is if I clear the `Enddate` the `maxDate` in `Startdate` will be removed it can select again the whole 12 months.

## **HTML**

```
< input type="text" id = "TrainingProgram_DateStarted" >
< input type="text" id = "TrainingProgram_DateEnded" >
```

## **JS**

```
$("#TrainingProgram_DateStarted").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $("#TrainingProgram_DateEnded").datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
    }
});

$("#TrainingProgram_DateEnded").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $("#TrainingProgram_DateStarted").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateText);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x4zd9tq8/)

Comment: **i abovestand you. please *explain* more.**

Comment: Please try my fiddle so you can understand a bit if my explanation is not well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSelect` event of datepicker is triggered when value from datepicker is chosen. if you clear the input value, above event is not going to get triggered. You should have change event for enddate and check if value is empty. if empty then set maxDate of start input as null:

```
$("#TrainingProgram_DateEnded").change(function(){
  if($(this).text().trim().length == 0)
   $("#TrainingProgram_DateStarted").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', null);
 }).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
       $("#TrainingProgram_DateStarted").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateText);
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8oLcu9u5/)**

Comment: I try the `.change` function but I didn't try the `trim and length`.. Thanks

Comment: @Yukki: glad it helps :)